# Backbone.js for in-browser page layout editor?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, backbone.js, django-models

I'm working on a web application which allows the user to edit elements on a page (much like you can do with Adobe InDesign). Objects can be dragged, selected and the user is provided with a sidebar which contains all properties of the object that can be modified.

The data is stored on the server in a database. I'm using *Django* with *tastypie* to provide a simple REST interface to the data in the database.

Basically the data is structured as follows:

- Document

  - Page

    - Page Objects

I've done some tests with jQuery and jQueryUI, which provide most of the code needed to allow object selection, drag+drop, etc. All good.

Now I'm considering what the best way is to store/manage/pull/update the information about all those objects on the page. I could do it all by hand, and use `jQuery.ajax()` and store information in arrays, dictionaries and link them to DOM elements. However, I feel there is quite a bit of reinventing the wheel and boilerplate code involved that could be avoided.

So I searched the web and came across Backbone.js. It reminds me a bit of Django's ORM and seemingly makes it simpler to manage all the data. As far as I understand the idea of Backbone.js it allows me to create a object class similar to that defined in the models on the server and use that to store all the information about an object.

Would it be suitable to use Backbone.js for this task? I've looked through its documentation and also saw it has support for doing the synchronization using REST/Ajax.

Comment: Great, do you plan to open-source it? I'm working on a similar project at its very draft stage. I'm using knockout.js for UI and html5sortable for DND (I found its a bit hard for drag'n'drop among nested widgets though) and customized JSON format..I'm not sure whether backbone.js helps we'll see.

Comment: @okm: No, this is for a commercial project, so I can't open-source it.

Comment: I see.. keep work on it and good luck =)

Answer (score 2):

Backbone may be suitable for your needs because it does provide **an abstraction for managing your data** in a way that is not coupled to the DOM, namely through `Backbone.Model` and `Backbone.Collection`.

The Backbone Models and Collections make it easy to mange the communication with your backend by **handling the AJAX life cycle**. It also has useful conventions for doing things like client side validation and pub/sub around model attribute changes.

Another important thing to note is that Backbone is easy to use in a piecemeal fashion. You can take advantage of the Models concept and ignore the views/routers or just use it for event management, etc.

The documentation is quite good. [Have a look.](http://backbonejs.org/)

Comment: Now that I've spend some time with backbone.js, it looks more and more like what I need. Seemingly I have to tweak the Model's code a little so that responses are correctly parsed since I'm using tastypie on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) is an excellent tool with no time manages to make an application (not trivial) for the generation of service quality surveys. and have done with emberjs appreciate. as it is the first time where he stayed php server side completely and not use it for more than the REST.

Also has excellent [documentation](http://emberjs.com/documentation/) and is very easy to extend.